# Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve information from environment bootmaster source(s)

Tags: puppet, directory, files

Feeling like a complete newbie to puppet (I admit I am very rusty :-)

So my manifest/site.pp file contains.

```
 file {"/tmp/findme.txt":
    source => "puppet:///modules/concat/concatfragments.rb"
  }


  file { "/etc/pupppetlabs/code/":
    path => "/etc/puppetlabs/code/",
    source  => "puppet:///modules/puppetEnv/code/",
    recurse => true
  }
```

The first file copy works just fine.  I find the file in /tmp/findme.txt, but the 2nd file copy (actually a directory copy) doesn't work.  It gets and error of

```
==> puppetmaster: Error: /Stage[main]/Main/Node[puppetmaster]/File[/etc/pupppetlabs/code/]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve information from environment bootmaster source(s) puppet:///modules/puppetEnv/code
```

Other pieces of information.

from my Vagrantfile

```
 pm.vm.provision "puppet" do |puppet|
   # puppet.options = "--verbose --debug"
    puppet.environment_path = "code/environments"
    puppet.environment = "bootmaster"
  end
```

Looking at the resulting /tmp/vagrant-puppet directory on the vm (where vagrant puts the puppet files) things look fine.

```
[vagrant@puppetmaster vagrant-puppet]$ tree -d
.
├── environments
│   ├── bootmaster
│   │   ├── manifests
│   │   └── modules
│   │       ├── baseconfig
│   │       │   └── manifests
│   │       ├── concat
│   │       │   ├── files
│   │       │   ├── lib
. . . 
│   │       ├── puppetEnv
│   │       │   ├── files
│   │       │   │   └── code
│   │       │   │       └── environments
│   │       │   │           └── test
│   │       │   │               ├── manifests
│   │       │   │               └── modules
```

Comment: Sorry, But I don't see code directory in your tree -d output

Answer (score 0):

Your problem looks to be the trailing slash in your paths.

You also don't need to specify the `path` as it's inherited from the resource's name, and it's always best to explicitly `ensure` that it's a directory for code readability.

Example:

```
file { '/etc/pupppetlabs/code':
  ensure  => directory,
  source  => 'puppet:///modules/puppetEnv/code',
  recurse => true,
}
```